# how to implement tighter encapsulation

Tags: c#

I have a method that I want to access from only one method because it is very specific and could confuse the programmers if they "see" that method from the other parts of the class. On the other hand, for unit testing and for readability, I have to make that method.

Is there any trick to encapsulate further than usual?

Just to make sure my idea is clear: method A calls method B. I want intellisense to show method B only if I am in method A.

Comment: please not that the term `function` doesn't exist in C#. `Method` is the right.

Comment: What you want is a programming language which allows proper nested block structure :) How about an anonymous method or lambda expression?

Comment: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3853 but i still does not understand why would you validate thinks within you're own Class !

Comment: Just make everything public. Stop trying to protect developers from themselves.  http://theprogrammersparadox.blogspot.com/2007/10/goto-next-goto.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the caller of the method, execute your method body only if the caller name matches (assuming you have only 1 method of that name, otherwise you have to check the arguments as well).

Not possible to hide this in intellisense though. Furthermore create a region in the class for the *DO NOT USE* method.

```
private void Func3()
{
    // Will not execute the method body
    Func2();
}

private void Func1()
{
    // Will execute the method body
    Func2();
}

private void Func2()
{
    var callingMethodName = new StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod().Name;
    if (string.Equals(callingMethodName, "Func1"))
    {
        // Execute your method's code....
    }
}
```

### An alternative approach using Attributes

Rather than hard coding the method name, you can create a custom attribute and mark your method with it to indicate that you are allowing this caller to execute your `DoNotUseMethod()`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
class AllowedMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AllowedMethodAttribute(bool methodAllowed)
    {
        this.AllowedToExecute = methodAllowed;
    }

    public bool AllowedToExecute { get; private set; }
}
```

And in your class use the attribute as follows,

```
private void AnotherNotAllowedMethod()
{
    MyDoNotUseMethod();
}

[AllowedMethod(false)]
private void NotAllowedMethod()
{
    MyDoNotUseMethod();
}

[AllowedMethod(true)]
private void MyAllowedMethod()
{
    MyDoNotUseMethod();
}

#region DoNotUseMethod 

private void MyDoNotUseMethod()
{
    var callingMethod = new StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod();
    var allowedMethodAttributes = callingMethod.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (AllowedMethodAttribute), false);
    if(allowedMethodAttributes.Length == 1)
    {
        var allowedMethodAttribute = allowedMethodAttributes[0] as AllowedMethodAttribute;
        if(allowedMethodAttribute != null && allowedMethodAttribute.AllowedToExecute)
        {
            // Execute the method body
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, callingMethod.Name + " is not allowed to execute this method", 
                "Mark method with AllowedMethod(true) attribute to allow execution of this method");
            // throw exception if required
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, callingMethod.Name + " is not allowed to execute this method", 
            "Mark method with AllowedMethod(true) attribute to allow execution of this method");
        // throw exception if required
    }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Ouch! A neat tick, but a maintenance nightmare: It has a "Func1" magic string, it breaks when the compiler decides to do inlining, and, worst of all, it fails silently (instead of throwing some kind of exception).

Comment: You are right. Hopefully, the second approach eradicates the hard coding!

Comment: The second approach seems like a very nice alternative and seems to hold water.

Comment: This is also INSANELY slow. The call to get the stackframe is VERY expensive. I've had to back out using it in production because it is so slow. I learned the hard way to avoid it.

Comment: Clever code, but not for production software. It is a terrible hack to circumvent a poor design. Never do this for real.

Answer (score 14):

If method B is only related to method A, you may want to revisit the design of the class because you could be violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

That being said, you could implement method B anonymously in the body of method A.  In my opinion, this detracts from readability but does yield the behavior you want.

Comment: +1. Reviewing class design can sometimes yield solutions of the problem :)

Answer (score 5):

You could make method B available as a delegate variable (e.g. `Func<T>`, `Action<T>`, etc.) within method A, but depending on the size of method B, that could get ugly:

```
private void MethodA()
{
    // Will only be available within MethodA's scope, but has access
    // to all members of the class, just as MethodA does.
    Func<int> methodB = delegate()
    {
        return 42;
    };

    methodB();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Extract that the methods into another class. MethodA is public and calls MethodB. Make MethodB private.

By the sounds of it they comprise a single unit together.

Comment: +1 for good approach. A small addition: then a `delegate` must be used to access that `private` method.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't combine content of `Method B` into `Method A`? It can be called then from 'A' only.

Comment: It is possible through the use an anonymous delegate/lambda expression. However, there may be better ways to reorganize the code.

Comment: @Fish I mean if the return type of `B` is `void` :)

Comment: If return type of B is void then you would just assign the anonymous delegate to an `Action<T>` instead of the `Func<T>`. The return type of B holds no bearing on whether this is plausible.